# Extract string before last comma in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to extract the whole string before the last comma. Please check the below example.

Example:
A1= Mon, this is a test, Wed, Sun, Sat, 2001 world

The result should be:
B1 = Mon, this is a test, Wed, Sun, Sat

Thanks in advance.
Vineet

Answer (score 1):

We can use a regex replacement here:

```
REGEXREPLACE(A1, ",[^,]*$", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "(.*),")
```

[image]